# Unable to split imported CSV column

Tags: pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, python-3.8

Help Please!!!

I've not be able to find a solution to this, and it's affecting my mental health :)

I have a CSV file, with UTF-8 encoding and am reading it in as follows;

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

file = ('BL-Flickr-Images-Book.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
```

[image]
1- the result of df.head() is an index and then a (`str`) single column - why?
2- I tried to split using `df[['A', 'B']] = df['AB'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)`

I also converted it to pd.Series and and to_frame() but the result is the same - as above.

Any help or direction will be brilliant.

**Sample of CSV**

"Identifier,Edition Statement,Place of Publication,Date of Publication,Publisher,Title,Author,Contributors,Corporate Author,Corporate Contributors,Former owner,Engraver,Issuance type,Flickr URL,Shelfmarks"
"000000206,,London,1879 [1878],S. Tinsley & Co.,Walter Forbes. [A novel.] By A. A,A. A.,""FORBES, Walter."",,,,,monographic,http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/tags/sysnum000000206,British Library HMNTS 12641.b.30."
"000000216,,London; Virtue & Yorston,1868,Virtue & Co.,""All for Greed. [A novel. The dedication signed: A. A. A., i.e. Marie Pauline Rose, Baroness Blaze de Bury.]"",""A., A. A."",""BLAZE DE BURY, Marie Pauline Rose - Baroness"",,,,,monographic,http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/tags/sysnum000000216,British Library HMNTS 12626.cc.2."
"000000218,,London,1869,""Bradbury, Evans & Co."",""Love the Avenger. By the author of “All for Greed.” [The dedication signed: A. A. A., i.e. Marie Pauline Rose, Baroness Blaze de Bury.]"",""A., A. A."",""BLAZE DE BURY, Marie Pauline Rose - Baroness"",,,,,monographic,http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/tags/sysnum000000218,British Library HMNTS 12625.dd.1."
"000000472,,London,1851,James Darling,""Welsh Sketches, chiefly ecclesiastical, to the close of the twelfth century. By the author of “Proposals for Christian Union” (E. S. A. [i.e. Ernest Appleyard])"",""A., E. S."",""Appleyard, Ernest Silvanus."",,,,,monographic,http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/tags/sysnum000000472,British Library HMNTS 10369.bbb.15."

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV data has quotes in.  When parsing CSV data, parsers consider quotes (`"`) more important than the separator (`,` in this case).

Pandas thinks that the first column in your CSV file is...

```
"Identifier,Edition Statement,Place of Publication,Date of Publication,Publisher,Title,Author,Contributors,Corporate Author,Corporate Contributors,Former owner,Engraver,Issuance type,Flickr URL,Shelfmarks"
```

...because of the quotes.  If you remove the double quotes in the CSV it should parse like you want, however, your file looks pretty messy to me so I'm not sure how well it will work.

Comment: Its a copy past from a RealPython data cleaning exercise, so maybe that's why its like that. I will test it with a few lines to see if this is the problem, then will have to figure out a way of doing this programatically... thanks!

Comment: I thought it may work, but still doing the same - I took the first 4 rows, removed all the (") and replaced them with (') - still only bring back a single column. Thanks for trying, can't find an answer anywhere!